# Ruby 'require' unable to load such a file

Tags: ruby

I want to require file `all_class` from file `log_in_test.rb`.

[image]

I tried all kinds of `require` and `require_relative`, for example

```
#require "../../ib4b-template/features/page-object/all_class"
require_relative "page-object/all_class"
```

and they are not working. Can anyone kindly give me a hand?

Comment: Are you running cucumber?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
require_relative 'all_class' # without 'page-object/'
```

The most common way to solve this problem is using `File.dirname(__FILE__)`:

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'all_class')
```

Comment: @nzsquall whats your ruby version?

Comment: @UnknownI am using ruby 2.0.0p247

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
require_relative '../page_object/all_class'
```

*relative* to `support/log_in_test.rb`, `all_class.rb` lies in above path.

[`require`](http://extensions.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Kernel.html#M000039) doesn't find if the directory structure is not in the Ruby's library path.

Comment: Hi @kiddorails, have error as: "H:\My H Drive\Workspace\ib4b-template\features>ruby log_in_test.rb
log_in_test.rb:5:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- H:/My H Drive/Workspace/ib4b-template/page_object/all_class (LoadError) from log_in_test.rb:5:in `<main>'"

Answer (score 1):

```
require_relative './page_object/all_class.rb'
```

or

```
require_relative './page_object/all_class'
```

the '.rb' part is optional

You should use require_relative instead of require when you are working on a project and want to require one file from one of the directories into another.

You should use require to add gem libraries to your project.

Also, a good practice to use when working on a larger practice is to make a environment.rb file in the config folder and have that require all the the models and then having the executables requiring that environment file.

Answer (score 0):

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', '..','page-object', 'all_class')
```

Comment: Hi @Bala, have error as: "H:\My H Drive\Workspace\ib4b-template\features>ruby log_in_test.rb
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- ./../../page-object/all_class (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
        from log_in_test.rb:5:in `<main>'"